# how to role back resource group action in windows azure

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-resource-group

I did something that I don't fully understand.
I went to my azure account and pressed the 'resource group' icon.
There I marked all my existing resources and then I clicked the "+Add" button.
The result was that every resource I had becode 'resource group'.
How can I reverse this action?

All I wanted to do is open a new 'resource group' and move all my existing resources under this new resource group.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but a resource (like a storage account or App Service) cannot be converted into a Resource Group. Are you saying that extra Resource Groups were created? Please edit for clarity.

Comment: @DavidMakogon I assumed that resource can not be converted to resource group. However, as I said, when I was in the resource group page (and I had no resource group yet) I got a list of all my resources. I checked all of them and then I pressed the '+Add' button and to my surprise I got resource group for every resource, each of which is containing the resource itself. Now, I would love to delete that resource group but I'm afraid that it will delete the resourse itself. I puzzled of what to do.

Comment: The Resource Group page doesn't show individual resources, just the resource groups themselves, so this is still a bit confusing. Nevertheless: You can move a resource to a different resource group (just open the resource and you'll see `(change)` next to the current Resource Group in the overview of that resource. You're correct that, if you delete a Resource Group, all resources within that Resource Group are also deleted at that time, so you'd want to move a resource out first before deleting an unwanted Resource Group.

Comment: @DavidMakogon Thank you for the good advice. I'm doing this right now but some things don't move like sendgrid and others. Any ideas of how to deal with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to move resources from one resource group to another resource group, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/move-support-resources) and the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/move-resource-group-and-subscription). But please note that some resources are not supported moving. We can use the following [rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/resources/validatemoveresources) to check it.

```
POST https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subscription-id>/resourceGroups/<source-group>/validateMoveResources?api-version=2019-05-10
Authorization: Bearer <access-token>
Content-type: application/json

Body

{
 "resources": ["<resource-id-1>", "<resource-id-2>"],
 "targetResourceGroup": "/subscriptions/<subscription-id>/resourceGroups/<target-group>"
}
```

Comment: It is ashame that some resources are not moveable. Somebody did a poor work in Microsoft. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @dsb    Since you have on other concerns, could you please accept the answer? It may help more people who have similar issue